# append items to a existing page ajax similar to amazon show more items button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a page that shows 5 items i would like to have the button at the end to show more items

when pushed it will show 10 more items however it will not do any post back similar to amazon show more items on review your purchases page.

Comment: webforms or mvc? it can be done via ajax.

Comment: what have you tried?   Using jquery, it can be as simple as $.get(url, data, callback)

Comment: not yet will try it I'm very new to j query

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers here are for inifite page. What you are asking for is called lazy loading of images.

Plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Demo: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html

This is a simplified explanation:

1. Find window size and find the position of all images and their sizes
2. If the image is not within the window size, replace it with a placeholder of same size
3. When user presses the button, and position of image < scroll + window height, the image is loaded

Comment: ic would i be able to hide the content then when a button click is trigger it will show the data?